# Issue with formatting time zone for Joda DateTime from ISO String

Tags: android, jodatime, isodate

So time formatting and adjusting has always been my biggest nemesis in programing and I'm having some issues in Android/Java that I can't figure out. I get a timestamp from a server that is formatted in UTC (here's an example **2016-06-17T18:30:00-07:00**. Now this time needs to get formatted to the users local time (so for a user in PST it should show as 11:30AM) but so far whatever I try I either get 1AM or 6:30PM (so I know I'm doing something wrong I just don't know what). Here's what I've been trying to do

```
public static DateTime convertISOStringToDate(String inputString) {
//setup the ISO Date Formatter with GMT/UTC format
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()
            .withLocale(Locale.US)
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(0));
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(inputString);
    //now convert the datetime object to a local date time object
    DateTimeFormatter localFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    String localString = localFormatter.print(dateTime);
    DateTime localDateTime = localFormatter.parseDateTime(localString);
    return localDateTime;
```

So at this point I'm getting 1:30AM, so I know I'm messing it up somewhere in the conversion process but I can't figure it out. I've been trying to google around but so far haven't found much that use the ISODateTimeFormat parser so they don't work either when I try them.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a basic mis-understanding of how dates are represented.
A date (in almost every known programming language / library) is represented internally as an offset from a specific 'origin time', known as the 'Epoch'.

In java.util.Date as well as joda dates, the internal representation is the number of milliseconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1980, UTC.

As such, a date does not have a timezone. You only introduce a timezone when you format a date (turn it into a String representation of the date).

You have made the common mistake of parsing a String into a date object, serializing (printing) it back out with a different timezone than the the original string indicated, and then parsing back into a date again, expecting something to have changed. If you do that correctly, you will get back exactly the same date that you started with.

In your case, the "localString" that you get shows the correct time in the local timezone. I'm in EDT, which is UTC-4:00, and I correctly get 2016-06-17 21:30:00 as the result.

As I said, parsing that back into a DateTime, and then looking at it is useless, because:

- You'll get the same DateTime back that you started with
- Your IDE (or whatever you're using to inspect the DateTime) probably isn't showing what you expect.

You should re-evaluate what you're doing here, and whether you really need to "convert" the DateTime, or to just parse it, and really understand how date formatting works with respect to timezones.